# Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to learn node.js.

I have the following code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('src/views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hello from render', nav: ['Books', 'Author'] });
});
```

> Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory 
>   I have the file named index.ejs. How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Comment: like this `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
`

Comment: This solved it for me.. I was running express in a different module

Comment: Could you please mention, in which file I have to write this code? In server.ts file I found similar codes but starting with `server.***`, not app.***

Comment: @Satrughna It depends on your codebase, so I don't know in your specific case. This needs to be specified on the file where you're instantiating and configuring the express instance.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I fixed it.

```
app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: where do these lines go?

Comment: @fraxture in your server.js file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too. I have saved the index file as .html file. But it should be index.ejs. then it worked. Check that too

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a banal problem: when I named my 'views' folder, accidentally I typed a white space before the name, so the name was ' veiws', thus, ejs couldn't find the 'views' folder.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this error by writing below line befor my
app.set('viewengine' , 'ejs')

```
    app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
```

using path is more convenient ,also note to require path befor using it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, then I saved my index file inside the views folder. Now the issue is gone. Also add this line of code in your file
`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))`