# Node js does not work in Ubuntu via Nginx

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I am writing a simple server utility in Node js, using Express and EJS. Everything works fine on my windows computer.

I transferred the improvements to the ubuntu server, launched them via node index.js. And everything worked fine.

my code:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening'));
```

But then I transferred the work to the nginx service:
"systemctl enable node@Node_1C --now"

And that's where the problems begin. When sending a request, it is returned
"Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/views""

For some reason, when node is running through nginx, the program cannot find the executable file in the views folder.

I ask for help and I will be grateful for every answer. If necessary, I can provide additional information.

I tried restarting the server, restarting the service. Nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It helped that:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Found here:
[Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608841/failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory)